# E/AbstractTracker: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Tags: java, android, thread-safety, android-looper

I cannot figure out why this error keeps occuring. I just installed ver 2.3.3 of android studio and have the below basic code.

Any ideas of how I can fix this?

```
package com.example.eoinclancy.fantastictwo;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


}
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 


xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.eoinclancy.fantastictwo.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]